# Add Expression Builder programmatically

Tags: expression, builder

I have a custom expression builder which I register using  tag in web.config.

Is there a way to accomplish the same thing programmatically at startup?

Comment: If there's no answer, and I don't know the answer, what's to accept?

Comment: Checkout your other questions.